# render a partial for every single item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, partial

I've got a load of clients in an each which I want to be able to loop(or show one) on different occassions. I thought I was clever and use a partial for a single client.

It seems that the partial is not being rendered though. If I just but some plain 'asd' in it or the real deal it shows nothing on my page either way.

I'm pretty sure there are clients present though.

Is there something wrong with my code?:

my **clients/index.html.erb**

```
<% @usersGroups.each do |group| %>
  <h1><%= group.name %></h1><br><br>
  <% if group.clients.length > 0 %>
    <% group.clients.each do |client| %>
      <% render partial: 'single_client', locals: {cl: client} %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    Nog geen clienten in deze groep.
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and my **clients/_single_client.html.erb**

```
xx<%= cl %> xx
<%= link_to(cl.name, edit_client_path(cl)) %>
<br>
<% if cl.avatar %>
    <img src="<%= cl.avatar %>" width="80">
<% end %>
<br>
<%= cl.birthdate.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")%>
<br>
<% if cl.background %>
<div style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 30px; height: 30px; background: <%= cl.background %>"></div>
<% end %>

<br><br>
<%= link_to(cl.group.name, group_path(cl.group)) if cl.group %><br>
<%= link_to 'Verwijder', cl, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Weet u zeker dat u #{cl.name} wil verwijderen?" } %>
```

I've tried using `render 'single_client'` aswell, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
<% group.clients.each do |client| %>
  <% render partial: 'single_client', locals: {cl: client} %>
<% end %>
```

try

```
<%= render partial: 'single_client', collection: group.clients %>
```

Comment: What data am I receiving in my partial now? Since `cl` is obviously broke if I don't set it in my local :D

Comment: Never mind. adding `, as: :cl` after collection did the trick.

Comment: Aaanndd I'm back. I'm trying to add it to my clients/show.html.erb but doesn't seem to work(I think because there's no collection??) How do I get `@client` in a CL variable in my partial nontheless?
`<%= render partial: 'clients/single_client', collection: @client, as: :cl %>`

Comment: @CaptainCarl I'm not what the variable is named (without the `:as` option), might be `client` or `single_client`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
<% render partial
```

With:

```
<%= render partial
```

Comment: Although your answer is correct I'm going with Thomas' answer. It saves me from adding a .each loop.

Comment: btw you dont need to wrap the partial rendering in `<% if group.clients.length > 0 %>`